# Which encryption returns 192 hash value it means 96 in bytes?

Tags: ida, assembly, debugging, obfuscation, shared-object

I am reversing an APK and there is a **signature** that needs to be found.
The function from where the signature is generated is present in the **.so** file.

I did **small debugging**. While doing it, the debugger shows all other processes, and when it is actually creating a signature, it automatically returns from the **.so** file to the apk and give the result in byte array format which is 92 of length, and after converting it to hex, it returns 192 hash value.

For all the input cases input length is 100 or 1000 the output hash value is 192.

Can anyone help me like which encryption gives **192 hash value**?

I got all the information except the actual signature generation part. I can also share the assembly code if someone wants to help me.

Comment: 192 what? Bits, bytes? Please add units to your numbers.

Comment: 192 has value it means 96 bytes

Comment: The question makes no sense as it is now. Try to edit and rephrase it.